# Rails 5 - Acts as Taggable On - is this gem deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I have been trying all year to learn how to use the Acts as Taggable On gem.

The tutorials are very old and out of date. The issues I've opened on the gem documentation have been ignored.

These two posts are my most recent posts looking for help - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170126154503/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517183/rails-5-acts-as-taggable-setup) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561256/rails-4-acts-as-taggable-on-gem-set-up-errors). I've seen others with similar questions not get any responses to those questions either.

Someone on codementor.io offered a paid session to show me how to build my own solution - suggesting that its necessary because the gem is out of date. Is this correct?

So - is that because there is another way to do this instead of using the gem?

I found this [site point tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/tagging-scratch-rails/) - but before I try to build my own tagging system - is there something obvious for why Acts as Taggable On is no longer supported?

Comment: Its not deprecated, try to see https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: No - yours isn't the solution. For rails 5  - the GitHub version is what works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this version of gem.This worked for me.

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 4.0'
```

Comment: Did you get it working for the use case I outlined in my post?

Comment: Did it work for you now?? If it did work then please upvote my answer.

Comment: This did not work for me...the gem is updated, but I keep getting the warning

Comment: It's at version 5.0 now gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 5.0'